# Query stopped running instead of inserting zero values

Tags: php, mysql

We have this MySQL query where we want to find the `date_time` and `price_open` from `price` table and update these two values into the `price_datetime` and `price_open` columns in `comment` table:

```
UPDATE comment AS fc 
    INNER JOIN price AS p
        ON  p.ticker_id = fc.ticker_id 
        AND p.date_time = 
            ( SELECT pi.date_time
              FROM price AS pi
              WHERE pi.ticker_id = fc.ticker_id 
                AND pi.date_time >= fc.date_time
              ORDER BY pi.date_time ASC
              LIMIT 1
            )  SET
    fc.price_datetime = p.date_time, 
    fc.price_open = p.price_open;
```

Which we converted to PHP+MySQL hoping for a more efficiency and much faster process:

```
<?php
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    usleep(160);

    $tickers =  array();

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ticker_id, date_time FROM flaggedcomment order by ticker_id, date_time");
    $stmt->execute(); //Execute prepared Query
    $stmt->bind_result($tid, $dt);
    $arr_index = 0;
    while ($stmt->fetch() ) {
        $tickers[$arr_index] = array();
        $tickers[$arr_index]["id"] = $tid;
        $tickers[$arr_index]["dt"] = $dt;
        $arr_index++;
    }
    /* free result set */
    $stmt->free_result();
    $record_index = 0;
    $flaggedcomment_index = 0;
    $sql = "";
        // get total tickers
        $total_tickers = count($tickers); 
         echo "Total records: " . $total_tickers . "<br />";

    foreach ($tickers as $ticker) { //fetch values

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT price_open, date_time FROM price WHERE ticker_id =? AND date_time >=? ORDER BY date_time ASC LIMIT 1;");

        $stmt->bind_param("is",$ticker["id"], $ticker["dt"]); // two params: one is integer, and other one is string

        $stmt->execute(); //Execute prepared Query

        $results = $stmt->get_result();
        $myrow =  $results->fetch_row();

            $set_string = "SET";
            // bind values
            $price_open = $myrow[0];
            $date_time = $myrow[1];

            // set initial insert query value
           $set_string .= " price_datetime='". $date_time ."'";
           $set_string .= ", price_open=". $price_open;
           $set_string .= " WHERE ticker_id=". $ticker["id"] ." AND date_time='" . $ticker["dt"] ."'";

            if($set_string != ""){
                $sql .= "UPDATE flaggedcomment ". $set_string . ";";
            }

            $idx = $record_index + 1;

            if(($record_index + 1) % 100 == 0){
            ?>
                    <script> 
                        $('#page-wrap > h1').html("Processing Ticker id #" + <?= $ticker["id"]; ?> + " - Record #" + <?= $idx; ?>);
                    </script>
        <?php 
                ob_flush();
                flush();

                usleep(160);
            }

            $record_index++;

        /* free result set */
        $stmt->free_result();
    } // end while fetch ticker id


        $update_flaggedcomment_qry = "LOCK TABLES flaggedcomment WRITE; ". $sql . "UNLOCK TABLES; ";
        echo $update_flaggedcomment_qry;
        //echo "<br />";
        if ($mysqli->multi_query($update_flaggedcomment_qry)) {
            // nothing
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . $mysqli->error . "<br />";
            $mysqli->close();
            exit;
       }

    echo "<span style='color:blue;'> <b> Done. </b> </span>";

    ob_end_flush();

    exit;

?>
```

Using the MySQL query, if there's no match of `ticker_id` and `date_time` from both tables, the `fc.price_datetime` and `fc.price_open` columns will show `0000-00-00 00:00:00` and `0.00` values. However, when executing the PHP code, instead of inserting the zero values, it will stop when it encounters its very first "no matching" of `ticker_id` and `date_time` and cannot continue. We've spent a long time figuring out on how to fix it, unfortunately, none of the ways we use can fix this.

Any help from the community is definitely much appreciated.

Thank you. :)

Comment: If you want to "insert into the comment table", why are you using `update`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry, wrong term being used, I want to `update`, because there's already existing columns filled with info. I will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not check if there is a record returned from *price* . Hence your code just tries picking the first and second elements of the result array when that array is null. You then likely land up with a statement trying to assign blank to each of the *price_datetime* and *price_open* fields. With the *price_datetime* you have quotes around the empty value and mysql will probably cope with this, but for *price_open* you do not have quotes around the expected numeric value. Hence you will land up with an invalid update statement (some like the following):-

```
UPDATE flaggedcomment price_datetime='', price_open= WHERE ticker_id=123 AND date_time='2016-01-01 00:00:00';
```

As you are executing multiple SQL statements at once to do the updates, I expect that it won't execute any after the invalid statement.

A quick play with your code and the following should work. This checks the returned row and if one isn't found it just uses the default (zero like) values for the 2 fields you want to update.

```
<?php
ob_flush();
flush();
usleep(160);

$tickers =  array();

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ticker_id, date_time FROM flaggedcomment order by ticker_id, date_time");
$stmt->execute(); //Execute prepared Query
$stmt->bind_result($tid, $dt);
$arr_index = 0;
while ($stmt->fetch() ) 
{
    $tickers[$arr_index] = array();
    $tickers[$arr_index]["id"] = $tid;
    $tickers[$arr_index]["dt"] = $dt;
    $arr_index++;
}
/* free result set */
$stmt->free_result();
$record_index = 0;
$flaggedcomment_index = 0;
$sql = "";
// get total tickers
$total_tickers = count($tickers); 
echo "Total records: " . $total_tickers . "<br />";

foreach ($tickers as $ticker) 
{ //fetch values

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT price_open, date_time FROM price WHERE ticker_id =? AND date_time >=? ORDER BY date_time ASC LIMIT 1;");

    $stmt->bind_param("is",$ticker["id"], $ticker["dt"]); // two params: one is integer, and other one is string

    $stmt->execute(); //Execute prepared Query

    $results = $stmt->get_result();
    if ($myrow =  $results->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $price_open = $myrow['price_open'];
        $date_time = $myrow['date_time'];
    }
    else
    {
        $price_open = 0.00;
        $date_time = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
    }

    $sql .= "UPDATE flaggedcomment SET";
    $sql .= " price_datetime='". $date_time ."'";
    $sql .= ", price_open=".$price_open;
    $sql .= " WHERE ticker_id=". $ticker["id"] ." AND date_time='" . $ticker["dt"] ."';";

    $idx = $record_index++;

    if(($record_index + 1) % 100 == 0)
    {
        ?>
        <script> 
        $('#page-wrap > h1').html("Processing Ticker id #" + <?= $ticker["id"]; ?> + " - Record #" + <?= $idx; ?>);
        </script>
        <?php 
        ob_flush();
        flush();

        usleep(160);
    }

    $record_index++;

    /* free result set */
    $stmt->free_result();
} // end while fetch ticker id


$update_flaggedcomment_qry = "LOCK TABLES flaggedcomment WRITE; ". $sql . "UNLOCK TABLES; ";
echo $update_flaggedcomment_qry;
//echo "<br />";
if ($mysqli->multi_query($update_flaggedcomment_qry)) {
    // nothing
} 
else 
{
    echo "Error updating record: " . $mysqli->error . "<br />";
    $mysqli->close();
    exit;
}

echo "<span style='color:blue;'> <b> Done. </b> </span>";

ob_end_flush();

exit;

?>
```

However I suspect that looping around the result of one query and doing another query for each row in php will be slower than a well constructed single update query.

If you do want to loop around the results like you are doing now it may be quicker to create a tmp table and insert the rows to that (as you can insert hundreds of rows with a single statement) and then update your *flaggedcomment* table with a single update statement that joins it to the tmp table

EDIT - If you can post the table declares and a bit of sample data I will have an attempt at doing it in a single SQL statement.

A first attempt (untested) would be:-

```
UPDATE comment AS fc 
INNER JOIN price AS p
ON  p.ticker_id = fc.ticker_id 
INNER JOIN 
( 
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT fc.ticker_id,
                MIN(pi.date_time) AS date_time
        FROM comment AS fc 
        INNER JOIN price AS pi
        ON pi.ticker_id = fc.ticker_id 
        AND pi.date_time >= fc.date_time
        GROUP BY fc.ticker_id
    ) sub1
) sub0
ON p.ticker_id = sub0.ticker_id
AND p.date_time = sub0.date_time
SET fc.price_datetime = p.date_time, 
    fc.price_open = p.price_open;
```

This is using the extra seemingly redundant sub query to hopefully bypass a MySQL restriction on updating a table that is also used in a subquery.

Comment: Hi Kickstart, sorry for the late response, as I was testing both of your solutions. Your MySQL query is more efficient (almost by half) than my original MySQL query. I've also tested using your PHP+MySQL code on my dataset, this works well too! PHP+MySQL takes only a few hours, which is way more efficient than the MySQL-only query. Thank you very much for your help and detailed explanation! We can see where our mistakes are. :)))